# Uploading an Android library with gradle and BinTray. Package after upload is always "com.xxx.xxx.app.vers" instead of "com.xxx.xxx.LibraryName.vers"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to upload a library to Maven/BinTray through gradle. After a long period of trial and error, I managed to upload it.

[image]

As you can see, the resulting package is "app" instead of "libraryName".

Here is my build.gradle (top level)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
 allprojects {
     repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle (app level):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {

}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

}

ext {
bintrayRepo = 'maven'
bintrayName = [...] 

publishedGroupId = [...]
libraryName = [...]
artifact = 'libraryName'

libraryDescription = [...]

siteUrl = [...]
gitUrl = [...]

libraryVersion = '1.0'

developerId = [...]
developerName = [...]
developerEmail = [...]

licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smasoumi/Bintray/master/install.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smasoumi/Bintray/master/bintray.gradle'
```

Here is my settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name = 'libraryName'
```

Things I have tried:

Setting the rootProject.name ="..." as specified in the android-maven-gradle documentation. Did not work.

Adding "artifact" in the ext {} - Did not work.

Setting the artifact name same as rootProject.name. Did not work.

Has anyone encountered this problem and can help me? Thank you!

Comment: You need to change the name of the project in the `settings.gradle`, but not the root project name. And the question has nothing to do with [maven], [bintray] and [jcenter]

Comment: Ok, and how do I do that?

Comment: In the documentation for maven, that exact command was specified.

Comment: I've also encountered the same problem. There's a discussion: https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/9